# Different editions of Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

I come from a Win32 .NET background. T

here are different editions of Eclipse including:

`Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers`, `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` , ...

I want to create a website with a JAVAEE stack.  I want to use Spring, JavaScript, and CSS for my front-end.

Which version should I select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "[Compare Eclipse packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php)".

You will get the [full content of each Eclipse distribution](http://www.eclipse.org/epp/content.php).

The difference is explained in "[What is Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_Eclipse?)" (emphasis mine).

> **Eclipse means a lot of different things to different people**.
>   To some Eclipse is a free, state-of-the-art Java development environment.
>   To others, Eclipse is a flexible environment to experiment with new computer languages or extensions to existing languages.
>   To yet others, Eclipse is a comprehensive framework that deploys many advanced and modern software design and implementation techniques.
>
> Eclipse is a platform because it is not a finished application per se but is designed to be extended indefinitely with more and more sophisticated tooling.

For any feature you might need, check out the [Eclipse MarketPlace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/), like the [one for Spring](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/156).
That should allow you to pick any Eclipse distro, and add through the marketplace Spring and all its dependencies.